# The change of fourier coefficients of a continuous function by a characteristic function

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

For $f \in C[0,2\pi]$ ; let $\hat f(n):=\dfrac 1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x)e^{-inx} dx , \forall n \in \mathbb Z$ . For any $A \subseteq \mathbb Z$ , let $f^A(n):=\hat f(n) . 1_A(n) , \forall n \in \mathbb Z$ ; where $1_A : \mathbb Z \to \{0,1\}$ denotes the characteristic (indicator) function of $A$ . Is it true that there exists infinite $A \subseteq \mathbb Z$ such that $ \mathbb Z \setminus A$ is infinite and for every $f \in C[0,2\pi] , \exists g \in C[0,2\pi]$ such that $\hat g(n)= f^A(n) , \forall n \in \mathbb Z $ ?

Comment: $$\frac{f(x)+f(x+\pi)}{2}$$

Comment: @reuns Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @Michelle ideally it is the OP who should use it to write an answer

Comment: Also characterizing such sets $A$ means characterizing distributions $T(x) =\frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{n \in A} e^{i \pi n}$ of order $0$.